# Check multiple array of data is existed in database mongodb node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to check the data is exist in a database. If suppose the data exist the value of k is set to 1

```
global.k = 0
va roll = {roll0:"1616",roll1:"234"}
for (let i = 0; i < inputcount; i++) {
  var obj1 = roll["roll" + i];

  const find = async() => {
    const item = await RegisterUser.find({ eventname: event_name, rollno: obj1 })
    if (item.length != 0) {
      global.k = 1
      console.log(global.k)
    } else {
      global.k = -1
      console.log(global.k)
    }
  }
  find()
}
  console.log(global.k)
if(global.k==0){
  // code for save
}
```

After if loop is executed, the value is not print as `1` or `-1`.Actually, I think the problem is in async. Please help me

Comment: Your code has more opening braces than closing.

Comment: Please fix the brackets. Not sure if `console.log()` is within the loop or outside

Comment: Again sorry sir, now please check my code

Comment: I tried but that page does not help for me, can you post sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `find` but don't await its result. Better make that `async` function something that wraps the whole loop:

```
const find = async() => {
  global.k = 0    
  for (let i = 0; i < inputcount; i++) {
    var obj1 = roll["roll" + i];    
    const item = await RegisterUser.find({ eventname: event_name, rollno: obj1 })
    if (item.length != 0) {
      global.k = 1
      console.log(global.k)
    } else {
      global.k = -1
      console.log(global.k)
    }
  }
  console.log(global.k);
  if (global.k == 0) {
     // save...
  }
}
find() // Don't put any code below this line. Put it at the end of the function above
```

NB: The algorithm itself looks strange, because every assignment to `global.k` overwrites the previous value that was assigned. The name for variable `k` does also not help to understand what its purpose is.

If you need it to be 1 when *all* queries return a match, then add a `break` here:

```
    } else {
      global.k = -1
      console.log(global.k)
      break;
    }
```

If you need it to be 1 when *at least one* query return a match, then add a `break` here:

```
    if (item.length != 0) {
      global.k = 1
      console.log(global.k)
      break;
    }
```

Also the check at the end `if (global.k == 0)` is strange, because that is equivalent to doing `if (inputcount == 0)`. So make sure to check your logic.

Comment: When I console inside `then` the value of k is 1 or -1 sir, but outside `then` the value is 0. Actually `then` is executed at last, before that outside function is excuted sir

Comment: That is exactly how it is supposed to work. You *must* do it within a `then` callback, because the database needs time to do its job. Alternatively, you must put *all* your code in an `async` function. Read about asynchronous code. You must go all the way and make all your code work with asynchrony.

Comment: sir please check the git repo sir https://gitlab.com/BalaRajendran/orlia2k19/blob/master/server/routes/index.js , I want to check the multiple data are exist in database all that data is not existed means the k value is 0 after that i will check the value of k if k is 0 i will save my save data into databse

Comment: Sorry, you should edit your question and put the *relevant* code there. Also explain what you mean with "check multiple data": explain what you want to send to the client. See my answer, and what I wrote near the end.

Comment: I had updated my question and my code sir, please check my updated code

Comment: I have updated my answer. So understand this: put everything in the `async` function, also the check and the saving to the database. Don't put any code *after* the call to `find`, because that code would execute too soon.

Comment: Thank You sir I fixed my issue